# Google apps container bound script custom modal dialog google.script.run.doSomething() onFailure() Authorization is required to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a Google sheet with a container bound script that runs an installed "On edit" trigger.

I recently added a pop up custom modal dialog to that trigger. It has a multi-select, a checkbox and two buttons.

The dialog html has a scriptlet that pulls information from the spreadsheet successfully to populate the multi-select.

Inside a script tag in the dialog, there is  a call to google.script.run to call a doSomething function that just calls the Logger, just as documented in the Google developer support pages for "HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) and "Class google.script.run (Client-side API)" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run").  The function is not called.

When I provide on onFailure handler, it returns: "ERROR: Authorization is required to perform that action." The sheet, script, html are all owned by my account and being run from my account.

These are the authorizations in the project scope: script.container.ui, script.send_mail, spreadsheets.currentonly.

How do I get google.script.run to run. Or, barring that, return information from the dialog to the spreadsheet.  Do I need to deploy the script as a web app? Thanks for any help.

Comment: onEdit() is a Simple Trigger. Simple Triggers have [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) such as that 
"They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous".

Comment: Yes, this script is using an Installable Trigger called, imaginatively, "installedOnEdit(e)" and it can and has sent emails successfully to the list of users that the sheet is shared with. I apologize if I wasn't clear enough about that.  The event it responds to is still just called "On edit" in the trigger installing dialog opened by the "Edit|Current project's triggers" menu. I'll change the spelling of the event in my post to better match the terms in that dialog drop-down.